# Logged user posts and public posts in REST

Tags: rest

In our application we have 2 functionalities: show a public list of posts, and show list of my(logged user) posts.

In public list of posts we show some data, and in my posts we show same as in public + something information that only logged user should see.

In this case, according to REST, should we make 1 endpoint or 2?

Comment: You have a misconception what REST is and why it should be used. It does not define how you should name your endpoints or how you should structure your endpoints. It is basically a generalization of the common Web targeted towards (autonomous) applications and agents rather then humans. By applying REST onto your architecture you basically want to have the freedom to change internals without affecting clients, i.e. change the URI structure. What most people seem to understand of REST has actually nothing to to with it. If you don't need above mentioned propertes, simply don't "do" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In public list of posts we show some data, and in my posts we show same as in public + something information that only logged user should see.

In REST, a resource is [any information that can be named](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).  Your description sounds like two different names (a public view of thing, and a private view of thing), so having two different resources could make sense.

There's nothing "wrong" with having two different resources that happen to share the same representation (either temporarily or permanently).

However, you need to keep in mind that -- as far as generic clients are concerned -- the two resources are *unrelated* to one another.  If we make a successful unsafe request to one resource, our local representations of that resource will be evicted from the cache, but our local representations of the *other* resource will not be evicted.

In other words, with two resources, you have to be willing to accept that they won't always be consistent with one another.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question/problem description correctly:
public list of posts - shows posts from all users
how list of my(logged user) posts - shows filtered list of posts + some extra info

From my perspective you should go for 2 endpoints as they return different objects, different errors and are addressed for different users. This way it would be clearer and easier to write in OpenAPI definition. Also It is more unequivocal to receive "Unauthorized" error than to get response containing only a part of expected content.

- `/posts`
- `/posts/{user_id}` where you can have special user_id = "mine"